# Common divisor of a string exists if $A \cdot B = B \cdot A$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, formal-languages

Let $A,B$ be nonempty strings over some finite alphabet and let $\cdot$ denote the concatenation operator. Let $s^{k}$ denote the string $s \cdot s \cdot s ... \cdot s$ concatenated itself exactly $k$ times.

If it is known that $A \cdot B = B \cdot A$, then show that there is a nonempty string $s$ such that $A = s^{k}$,$B = s^{j}$ for some positive integers $k,j$.

I believe the statement is true. In particular, I'm pretty sure the first $d = gcd(a,b)$ characters of $A$ must match that of $B$ and that it divides both strings evenly, but I'm not sure how to prove this hunch.

Comment: Induction on $\gcd(\vert A \vert, \vert B \vert)$?

Comment: Hint: Assume $|B|=m, |A|=n,$ and $n\geq m.$ Then the first and last $m$ letters of $A$ must both  be the same as $B.$

Comment: If $|A|=|B|$, then it's trivial. But when $|A|>|B|$, I am still not sure how the result follows. I tried considering a simpler case where $gcd(m,n)=1$ and showing that every character is the same then in that case, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s make all strings $0$-indexed for convenience.

Denote the length of $A$ and $B$ to be $a$ and $b$, respectively.

Denote $C = A \cdot B$. Then its length, denoted $n$, equals $a + b$.

From $A \cdot B = B \cdot A$ we can obtain, $C = \operatorname{rot}_b(C)$ where $\operatorname{rot}_k$ means a circular shift by $k$ to the right.

That is, $C_i = C_{(i + b) \bmod n}$ for all $i \in [0, n)$. Manipulate this relation to form equivalence classes, invoking results in number theory, we obtain $C_i = C_{i \bmod \gcd(b, n)}$ and hence the prefix of length $\gcd(b, n)$ is a repetend. Of course, $\gcd(b, n) = \gcd(a, b)$.

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on what results from number theory are used to obtain the result? I'm not sure how to proceed from the first relation you provided.

Comment: @user308485 The thing is we have $i$ and $(i + b) \bmod n$ are in the same equivalence class for all $i$. Therefore, $i$ and $(i + k \cdot b) \bmod n$ are in the same class, too, for integer $k$. The result from Bézout’s lemma tells us that $(k \cdot b) \bmod n$ are exactly multiples of $\gcd(b, n)$. Above result follows.